# Why does GDB "step" go into machine language of standard library call?

Tags: c, gdb

On some of my systems, while I'm debugging very simple code, GDB is behaving differently than I'd expect. On some systems, when I 'step', gdb "glosses over" standard library calls; on other systems, 'step' goes down into the machine language of each library call.

First, an example of the behavior I'm accustomed to from GDB:

```
$ gdb ./testapp
GNU gdb (GDB) CentOS (7.0.1-45.el5.centos)
(...)
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483b6: file testapp.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./testapp

Breakpoint 1, main () at testapp.c:6
6               char str[] = {"Test string"};
(gdb) step
8               printf("String: %s\n", str );
(gdb)
String: Test string
9               printf("Len: %zu\n", strlen( str ));
(gdb)
Len: 11
10              return 0;
(gdb)
```

Here's an example of GDB stepping down into the printf() to the machine language steps.

```
$ gdb ./testapp
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-92.el6)
(...)
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40050c: file testapp.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./testapp

Breakpoint 1, main () at testapp.c:6
6               char str[] = {"Test string"};
(gdb) step
8               printf("String: %s\n", str );
(gdb)
__printf (format=0x400668 "String: %s\n") at printf.c:30
30      {
(gdb)
34        va_start (arg, format);
(gdb)
35        done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
(gdb)
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x383958f040, format=0x400668 "String: %s\n", ap=0x7fffffffe330) at vfprintf.c:236
236       int save_errno = errno;
(gdb)
201     {
(gdb)
236       int save_errno = errno;
(gdb)
1283      ORIENT;
(gdb)
1287      ARGCHECK (s, format);
(gdb)
1298      if (UNBUFFERED_P (s))
(gdb)
1309      __va_copy (ap_save, ap);
(gdb)
1320      f = lead_str_end = __find_specmb ((const UCHAR_T *) format);
(gdb)
__find_specmb (s=0x383958f040, format=0x400668 "String: %s\n", ap=0x7fffffffe330) at printf-parse.h:109
109       return (const unsigned char *) __strchrnul ((const char *) format, '%');
(gdb)
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x383958f040, format=0x400668 "String: %s\n", ap=0x7fffffffe330) at vfprintf.c:1309
1309      __va_copy (ap_save, ap);
(gdb)
1320      f = lead_str_end = __find_specmb ((const UCHAR_T *) format);
(gdb)
__find_specmb (s=0x383958f040, format=0x400668 "String: %s\n", ap=0x7fffffffe330) at printf-parse.h:109
109       return (const unsigned char *) __strchrnul ((const char *) format, '%');
(gdb)
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S:27
27              movd    %esi, %xmm1
(gdb)
28              movq    %rdi, %rcx
(gdb)
29              punpcklbw %xmm1, %xmm1
(gdb)
```

Here is the source for "testapp.c":

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char str[] = {"Test string"};

        printf("String: %s\n", str );
        printf("Len: %zu\n", strlen( str ));
        return 0;
}
```

The program was compiled, in both environments, as follows:

```
cc -g -o testapp testapp.c
```

This is my first question on Stack Overflow! Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: On RedHat-family systems such as CentOS, debugging symbols are sequestered into separate packages from the main application or library.  For the `printf()` function and others from the C standard library, the main package is named "glibc", and the debug symbols are in "glibc-debuginfo".  The former will always be installed, but the latter might well not be on some systems.

Comment: John! You're my hero!

I found the packages you referred to, and removed them by: ``yum remove glibc-debuginfo-common.x86_64 glibc-debuginfo.x86_64``. I re-ran my GDB session, and it no longer steps into those calls!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John's comment on the original post nailed it.

I found that the machine which was stepping down into the libraries had two debugging packages installed: `glibc-debuginfo` and `glibc-debuginfo-common`.

After removing them with `yum remove glibc-debuginfo glibc-debuginfo-common`, GDB now works the way I expected it to!

Many thanks, John!

Answer (score 4):

You don't see "machine language". You see the library's source code.

On some machines the library apparently is installed with debug info and source code. Doing a "step" on that machine will step into the procedure. On another machine the library is apparently not installed with debug info, so the "step" command steps over it.

Note: the "step" command should step into the library in all cases. If there is no source code, you should see (real) machine language. It seems gdb does not do this (VS does).

Comment: Paul,
Thank you for the response. My example didn't show the actual machine language, but rather showed how GDB was stepping into a library call, versus not doing so on the other machine. I kept the initial post terse, as I didn't want to provide too much information off the bat, but I assure you that GDB would step down to the machine language steps. I have updated the initial post with further detail including the machine language steps.

Comment: Chris, I still only see C language, not machine language such as `push bp; move bp,sp`

Comment: Look towards the very bottom of the second code block:
``27              movd    %esi, %xmm1
(gdb)
28              movq    %rdi, %rcx
(gdb)
29              punpcklbw %xmm1, %xmm1
``

Comment: Installing library source doesn't matter (i.e. this answer is slightly wrong). What matters is absence or presence of *debug info* (which allows GDB to *find* source code).

Comment: @employed: you need both, so the source matters too. Debig information only points to the source.

Comment: @rici You are mistaken: for the change in behavior of `step` you don't need source, only debug info.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mis-understanding about 'step' and 'next' commands to `gdb`.

'step' tries to execute to the next line of code in the path of execution (its' full name is 'step into'.

'next' tries to execute to the line of code following the current line. (it does not stop in a called function.